# Storing plot objects in a list

Tags: pdf, r, statistics, ggplot2, plot

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816480/generating-names-iteratively-in-r-for-storing-plots) question yesterday about storing a plot within an object. I tried implementing the first approach (aware that I did not specify that I was using `qplot()` in my original question) and noticed that it did not work as expected.

```
library(ggplot2)               # add ggplot2

string = "C:/example.pdf"      # Setup pdf
pdf(string,height=6,width=9)

x_range <- range(1,50)         # Specify Range

# Create a list to hold the plot objects.
pltList <- list()
pltList[]

for(i in 1 : 16){

# Organise data 
y = (1:50) * i * 1000                       # Get y col
x = (1:50)                                  # get x col
y = log(y)                                  # Use natural log

# Regression
lm.0 = lm(formula = y ~ x)                  # make linear model
inter = summary(lm.0)$coefficients[1,1]     # Get intercept
slop = summary(lm.0)$coefficients[2,1]      # Get slope

# Make plot name
pltName <- paste( 'a', i, sep = '' )

# make plot object    
p <- qplot(
    x, y,   
    xlab = "Radius [km]", 
    ylab = "Services [log]",
    xlim = x_range,
    main = paste("Sample",i)
) + geom_abline(intercept = inter, slope = slop, colour = "red", size = 1)        

print(p)     

pltList[[pltName]] = p       
}

# close the PDF file
dev.off()
```

I have used sample numbers in this case so the code runs if it is just copied. I did spend a few hours puzzling over this but I cannot figure out what is going wrong. It writes the first set of pdfs without problem, so I have 16 pdfs with the correct plots.

Then when I use this piece of code:

```
string = "C:/test_tabloid.pdf"
pdf(string, height = 11, width = 17)

grid.newpage()
pushViewport( viewport( layout = grid.layout(3, 3) ) )

vplayout <- function(x, y){viewport(layout.pos.row = x, layout.pos.col = y)}

counter = 1

# Page 1
for (i in 1:3){    
    for (j in 1:3){     
         pltName <- paste( 'a', counter, sep = '' )   
         print( pltList[[pltName]], vp = vplayout(i,j) )
         counter = counter + 1
     }
 }

 dev.off()
```

the result I get is the last linear model line (`abline`) on every graph, but the data does not change. When I check my list of plots, it seems that all of them become overwritten by the most recent plot (with the exception of the `abline` object).

A less important secondary question was how to generate a muli-page pdf with several plots on each page, but the main goal of my code was to store the plots in a list that I could access at a later date.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, so if your plot command is changed to

```
p <- qplot(data = data.frame(x = x, y = y),
           x, y,   
           xlab = "Radius [km]", 
           ylab = "Services [log]",
           xlim = x_range,
           ylim = c(0,10),
           main = paste("Sample",i)
           ) + geom_abline(intercept = inter, slope = slop, colour = "red", size = 1)
```

then everything works as expected.  Here's what I suspect is happening (although Hadley could probably clarify things).  When ggplot2 "saves" the data, what it actually does is save a data frame, and the names of the parameters.  So for the command as I have given it, you get

```
> summary(pltList[["a1"]])
data: x, y [50x2]
mapping:  x = x, y = y
scales:   x, y 
faceting: facet_grid(. ~ ., FALSE)
-----------------------------------
geom_point:  
stat_identity:  
position_identity: (width = NULL, height = NULL)

mapping: group = 1 
geom_abline: colour = red, size = 1 
stat_abline: intercept = 2.55595281266726, slope = 0.05543539319091 
position_identity: (width = NULL, height = NULL)
```

However, if you don't specify a `data` parameter in qplot, all the variables get evaluated in the current scope, because there is no attached (read: saved) data frame.

```
data: [0x0]
mapping:  x = x, y = y
scales:   x, y 
faceting: facet_grid(. ~ ., FALSE)
-----------------------------------
geom_point:  
stat_identity:  
position_identity: (width = NULL, height = NULL)

mapping: group = 1 
geom_abline: colour = red, size = 1 
stat_abline: intercept = 2.55595281266726, slope = 0.05543539319091 
position_identity: (width = NULL, height = NULL)
```

So when the plot is generated the second time around, rather than using the original values, it uses the *current* values of `x` and `y`.

Comment: Thanks RCS and Jonathan, this fixed the problem. I was unaware of the data argument and how it could be used to store the data. I'm examining that section of the book now.

Answer (score 5):

I think you should use the `data` argument in `qplot`, i.e., store your vectors in a data frame.

See Hadley's book, Section 4.4:

*The restriction on the data is simple: it must be a data frame. This is restrictive, and unlike other graphics packages in R. Lattice functions can take an optional data frame or use vectors directly from the global environment. ...*

*The data is stored in the plot object as a copy, not a reference. This has two
important consequences: if your data changes, the plot will not; and ggplot2 objects are entirely self-contained so that they can be save()d to disk and later load()ed and plotted without needing anything else from that session.*

Comment: I was having a similar problem like the OP. I was using `data.table`s, and adding `setDF(data)` in my loop solved my particular situation. (`copy(data)` did not work, interestingly.) Your quote on how ggplot interacts with data allowed me to find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in your code concerning list subscripting. It should be

```
pltList[[pltName]]
```

not

```
pltList[pltName]
```

Note:

```
class(pltList[1])
[1] "list"
```

pltList[1] is a *list* containing the first element of pltList.

```
class(pltList[[1]])
[1] "ggplot"
```

pltList[[1]] is the first *element* of pltList.

Comment: Sorry - I made a mistake with what I meant to paste. I did not fully understand the difference between the syntaxes and had been editing it to see the difference. However my error still exists as I describe above.

Answer (score 1):

For your second question: Multi-page pdfs are easy -- see `help(pdf)`:

```
 onefile: logical: if true (the default) allow multiple figures in one
          file.  If false, generate a file with name containing the
          page number for each page.  Defaults to ‘TRUE’.
```

For your main question, I don't understand if you want to store the *plot inputs* in a list for later processing, or the *plot outputs*.  If it is the latter, I am not sure that `plot()` returns an object you can store and retrieve.

Comment: I was hoping to store the plot outputs. If I store the plot inputs, does that include the values of x and y at that particular time?

Comment: Of course. Just store all function arguments etc in a list. That is very standard.  But your assumption of storing _plot output_ is not.  The plot results are device-dependent and most likely OS-dependent.  Just write to a file, possibly a bitmap, and display that.  Or write GUI style apps.  Or just open multiple plot windows.

Comment: However, `ggplot` may well return objects to you. In which case Eduardo's answer is your key.

Comment: ggplot graphs are indeed constructed by creating a specification which is that converted into a graph by using the print.ggplot() method. So you can (handily!) create a ggplot object without printing it, then use ggsave() to save it to a PDF directly. Or use save() to just save the data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion regarding your second question would be to use either Sweave or Brew as they will give you complete control over how you display your multi-page pdf.

Have a look [at this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429907/workflow-for-statistical-analysis-and-report-writing).