# display multiple plots with a for loop using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, list, loops, for-loop, ggplot2

I am trying to display multiple plots at once using ggplot2 in R.

There are more than 200 cities in the data but I created just a random sample data as follows:

```
#sample data

df <- data.frame(
    city = c('paris', 'tokyo', 'seoul', 'shanghai', 'berlin', 'rome')
    , week = c(41,42)
    , type = c('A','B','C')
    , count = sample(1:100, 24, replace = F)
    )

df <- data.table(df)
df[, .(count=sum(count)), by =.(city,type, week)]
```

In the original data, there are more than 200 cities, but I just created random data for this.

I would like to extract top 10 cities based on number of counts,
put the top 10 cities into a list,
and loop it to automatically plot out on viewer.

I could use facet_grid option, but for this purpose, I would need to figure this way.

[This article](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2015/05/14/r-ggplot-displaying-multiple-charts-with-a-for-loop/) has helped me to shape so far, but It's not working because I am not counting numeric values but factors to loop the graphs.

```
# function
plotCities <- function(cityName){
            df <- df[city == cityName,]
                    ggplot(df, 
                           aes(x = as.factor(week), y = count, 
                               color = as.factor(week), group = as.factor(week))) + 
                            scale_y_continuous(labels = comma) +
                            geom_point() + 
                            geom_line() + 
                            labs(title = "cities monthly counts",
                                 x = "month",
                                 y = "counts")+
                            theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=1))
    }

plotCities("paris")
```

This won't create nice graph but that doesn't matter at this point as the objective here is to plot multiple at display.

```
for(cityName in df$city) {
        plotCities(cityName)
}
```

Thought this would work but that didn't create the list I want to... so a fail.

My next attempt was:

```
   p <- list()
    for(i in 1:length(df$city)){
            cityName = df2[i, 1]
            p[[i]] = plotCities(cityName)

    }
```

which doesn't work probably because the city value is factor?

Please share me some tips!

Comment: `for(cityName in df$city) {
        print(plotCities(cityName))
}` Will output the graphs. However, there are a lot of repetitions. So maybe add `unique(df$city)`

Comment: This question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40366468/4477364 has information that might help.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `grid.arrange` from the `gridExtra` package. This can put multiple grid plots in one overall graph (works for both lattice and ggplot2).

In the following example I use `lapply` (and not a for loop) to create the list of plots, and `do.call` to run `grid.arrange` with the plot list:

```
library(gridExtra)
plot_list = lapply(unique(df$city), plotCities)
do.call('grid.arrange', plot_list)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've tried this out and constantly getting this following error: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(x, name, value) : 
  replacement has 17 rows, data has 226

Comment: You need to create a reproducible example (code and data that I can copy-paste into R and reproduce your issue) as the error you get can be caused by many things. Without that information it will be impossible for me to help you.