# Store multiple plots into a list using a function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to store multiple plots produced by `ggplot2` into a list.

I am attempting to use the list function suggested in a [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31993704/storing-ggplot-objects-in-a-list-from-within-loop-in-r), however I am having difficulty creating my own function to meet my needs.

First, I split a dataframe based on a factor into a list with the following code:

```
heatlist.germ <- split(heatlist.germ, f=as.factor(heatlist.germ$plot))
```

Afterwhich, I attempt to create a list function that I can later use `lapply` with.

```
plot_data_fcn <- function (heatlist.germ) {
  ggplot(heatlist.germ[[i]], aes(x=posX, y=posY, fill=germ_bin)) + 
    geom_tile(aes(fill=germ_bin)) + 
    geom_text(aes(label=germ_bin)) +
    scale_fill_gradient(low = "gray90", high="darkolivegreen4") +
    ggtitle(plot) +
    scale_x_continuous("Position X", breaks=seq(1,30)) +
    scale_y_continuous("Position Y (REVERSED)", breaks=seq(1,20))
  }

heatlist.test <- lapply(heatlist.germ[[i]], plot_data_fcn)
```

Two main things I am trying to accomplish:

1. Store the 12 ggplots (hence 12 factors of `plot`) in a list.
2. Create a title called "Plot [i] Germination".

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `plots <- lapply(heatlist.germ, plot_data_fcn)`, and remove the `[[i]]` from inside your function as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have your data, so I'll simplify the plotting mechanism.

The first problem is that you should not use your `[[i]]` referencing in your function. Just have your function deal with data as-is, it really doesn't know that its argument is (in another environment) an element with a list. It knows just the object itself.

```r
# a simple plot function
myfunc <- function(x) ggplot(x, aes_string(names(x)[1], names(x)[2])) + geom_point()
# a list of frames, nothing fancy here
datalist <- replicate(3, mtcars, simplify = FALSE)
# just call it ...
myplots <- lapply(datalist, myfunc)
class(myplots[[1]])
# [1] "gg"     "ggplot"
```

When `myfunc` is called, its argument `x` is just a `data.frame`, the function has no idea that `x` is the first (or second or third) frame in a list of frames.

If you want to include the nth frame with an index indicating which element it is, this is in my view "zipping" data together, so I suggest `Map`. (You can also use `purrr::imap` or related tidyverse functions.)

```r
myfunc2 <- function(x, title = "") ggplot(x, aes_string(names(x)[1], names(x)[2])) + geom_point() + labs(title = title)
myplots <- Map(myfunc2, datalist, sprintf("Plot number %s", seq_along(datalist)))
class(myplots[[1]])
# [1] "gg"     "ggplot"
```

To understand how `Map` relates to `lapply`, then understand that `lapply(datalist, myfunc)` is "unrolled" to something like:

```r
myfunc(datalist[[1]])
myfunc(datalist[[2]])
myfunc(datalist[[3]])
```

With `Map`, however, it takes one function that must accept one *or more* arguments in each call. With that, `Map` accepts as many lists (or vectors) as the function accepts arguments. The two functions are synonomously

```r
lapply(datalist, myfunc) # data first,     function second
Map(myfunc, datalist)    # function first, data second
```

and a more complicated call unrolls like thus:

```r
titles <- sprintf("Plot number %d", seq_along(datalist)) # "Plot number 1", ...
Map(myfunc2, datalist, titles)
# equivalent to
myfunc2(datalist[[1]], titles[[1]])
myfunc2(datalist[[2]], titles[[2]])
myfunc2(datalist[[3]], titles[[3]])
```

It doesn't really matter if each of the arguments is a true `list` (as in `datalist`) or a vector (as in `titles`), as long as they are the same length (or length 1).

Comment: Thank you very much!! This is a very thorough explanation of the behind-the-scenes of each function. I appreciate this answer much more as it expands my understanding of the code itself. Thank you!