# plotting custom functions in ggplot with variables from dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a set of custom functions in ggplot using multiple variables in a dataframe to calculate the function output. Here's a toy example with slopes and y-intersects stored as 'a' and 'b' in two columns of a data frame. One simple solution I was able to figure out is to manually cycle through the values. [output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqJtM.png)

```
library(ggplot2)
# define slope (a) and y intersect (b) of lines
df <- data.frame(a=c(2, 1), b=c(0, -5))
# plot lines with slopes (a) and y intersect (b)
plot <- ggplot() + xlim(-50, 50) +
     geom_function(fun = function(x) df$a[1]*x+df$b[1]) +
     geom_function(fun = function(x) df$a[2]*x+df$b[2])
print(plot)
```

If I use a for loop ggplot seems to replace the first function with the second function and I'm not really sure why? [output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkfcm.png)

```
library(ggplot2)
# define slope (a) and y intersect (b) of lines
df <- data.frame(a=c(2, 1), b=c(0, -5))
# plot lines with slopes (a) and y intersect (b)
plot <- ggplot() + xlim(-50, 50)
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {plot <- plot + geom_function(fun = function(x) df$a[i]*x+df$b[i])}
print(plot)
```

However, neither option is ideal in my eyes, but my intuitive solution clearly gives incorrect results. [output3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6qO9.png)

```
library(ggplot2)
# define slope (a) and y intersect (b) of lines
df <- data.frame(a=c(2, 1), b=c(0, -5))
# plot lines with slopes (a) and y intersect (b)
plot <- ggplot() + xlim(-50, 50) +
     geom_function(fun = function(x) df$a*x+df$b)
print(plot)
```

Is there no easy way to solve this within ggplot? I don't really want to create a new data frame for discrete x values to retain the option to plot functions instead of points connected by a line.

---

### Clarification

@Allan and @Magnus, I only chose the linear plots as the simplest example, but I would like to plot a custom function f(x) <- s/sqrt(x)/(2*c) for many s and c values. My current work-around has drawbacks (need to enumerate every pair of factors; only plots line connecting discrete data points not smooth function; ...). [output4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBsDg.png)

```
library(ggplot2)
# define s and c 
df <- data.frame(s=c(0.2, 0.5, 0.5), c=c(3, 5, 7))
# plot lines with function f(x) <- s/sqrt(x)/(2*c)
plot <- ggplot() + xlim(0, 50) +
     geom_line(data=data.frame(x=1:50, y=df$s[1]/sqrt(1:50/(2*df$c[1]))), aes(x=x, y=y)) +
     geom_line(data=data.frame(x=1:50, y=df$s[2]/sqrt(1:50/(2*df$c[2]))), aes(x=x, y=y)) +
     geom_line(data=data.frame(x=1:50, y=df$s[3]/sqrt(1:50/(2*df$c[3]))), aes(x=x, y=y))
print(plot)
```

My 'intuitive' solution of calling the plot without specifying the row item `geom_line(data=data.frame(x=1:50, y=df$s/sqrt(1:50/(2*df$c))), aes(x=x, y=y)` doesn't work and would only address part of the problem anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a couple of weeks with R the answer to my previous question is kinda obvious. I was simply not creating the layers the right way and the for-loop is inefficient at doing so anyway. Without going into the details of the data, I was performing a 'power analysis of some of our studies.
[image]

I was able to show the average behavior across all studies, but I wanted to overlay a graph of the power of the study against sample number based on the variance of all individual studies as well.

I simply added a function called by mapply to just add a bunch of additional layers that I can then append to the basic plot. `my_funct describes the relationship between n, cv, and power of the study.

```
#// function to plot layers of dashed line for each study
geom_layer <- function (study, cv) { geom_function(aes(color=study), fun = my_funct, args = (cv), alpha=.7, linetype="dashed", size = 1) }

#// set up geom_lines for all other studies and store in layers
layers <- mapply(geom_layer, data_stats$study, data_stats$cv, SIMPLIFY = F )

#// combine plot and layers
print(plot + layers)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are looking for. If you want to loop through a dataframe which consist of slopes and intercept values, then here is a way. The thing to keep in mind here is evaluation of expressions. See more info in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31993704/storing-ggplot-objects-in-a-list-from-within-loop-in-r) post. If this is not what you are looking for, please provide an example of the preferred output.

```r
library(ggplot2)

# Either
df <- data.frame(a=c(10, 5), b=c(50, -5))
plot <- ggplot()
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {print(plot + geom_function(fun = function(x) df$a[i]*x+df$b[i]))}
```

[image][image]

```r
# Or the list way to save each plot
df <- data.frame(a=c(10, 5), b=c(50, -5))
plot_list <- vector("list", nrow(df))
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  plot_list[[i]] <- local({
    i <- i
    p <- ggplot() + geom_function(fun = function(x) df$a[i]*x+df$b[i])
    print(p)
  })
}
```

[image][image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @Magnus. I am sorry that I wasn't clear enough in my question. I will amend the post in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all your lines on a single plot and you are planning to use simple straight lines with a slope and intercept, you could use `geom_abline`. To give a slightly expanded example:

```r
library(ggplot2)

# define slope (a) and y intersect (b) of lines
df <- data.frame(a = c(2, 1, -0.5, 1.5), b = c(0, -5, 5, 3))

# plot lines with slopes (a) and y intersect (b)
ggplot(df) + 
  xlim(-50, 50) +
  ylim(-50, 50) +
  geom_abline(aes(slope = a, intercept = b, color = factor(seq(nrow(df))))) +
  labs(color = "equation")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Allan. I think I should have been more clear that the linear plots are simply an example. I would like to do this for a custom non-linear function `f(x) <- s/sqrt(x)/(2*c)`. I will amend the post to make this more clear.