# Math Symbols within for loop of GGplots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, expression

I'm currently trying to develop a similar result as [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31993704/storing-ggplot-objects-in-a-list-from-within-loop-in-r). I have a significant number of columns and several different labels for the x-axis.

```
col1 <- c(2, 4, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 0, 1, 4, 4, 3, 5, 2, 4, 3, 3, 6, 5, 3, 6, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 
          2, 4, 3, 3, 5, 3, 5, 5, 0, 0, 3, 3, 6, 5, 4, 4, 1, 3, 3, 2, 0, 5, 3, 6, 6, 2, 3, 
          3, 1, 5, 3, 4, 6)
col2 <- c(2, 4, 4, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 4, 3, 5, 0, 4, 5, 3, 6, 5, 3, 6, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 
          1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 0, 3, 4, 2, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 2, 3, 5, 2, 6, 5, 2, 4, 6, 3, 3, 
          3, 1, 4, 3, 5, 4)
col3 <- c(2, 5, 4, 1, 4, 2, 3, 0, 1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 1, 4, 3, 4, 6, 3, 4, 6, 4, 1, 3, 5, 4, 3, 
          2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 0, 1, 4, 4, 3, 5, 3, 2, 5, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 5, 1, 3, 
          3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4)
col4 <- c(2, 5, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 3, 5, 3, 4, 6, 3, 4, 6, 4, 3, 2, 5, 5, 4,
          2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 0, 1, 4, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 5, 4, 3, 5, 3, 6, 6, 4, 2, 
          3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 6)
data2 <- data.frame(col1,col2,col3,col4)
data2[,1:4] <- lapply(data2[,1:4], as.factor)
colnames(data2)<- c("A","B","C", "D")

> x.axis.list

[[1]]
expression(beta[paste(1, ",", 1L)])

[[2]]
expression(beta[paste(1, ",", 2L)])

[[3]]
expression(beta[paste(1, ",", 3L)])

[[4]]
expression(beta[paste(1, ",", 4L)])

myplots <- vector('list', ncol(data2))

for (i in seq_along(data2)) {
    message(i)
    myplots[[i]] <- local({
        i <- i
        p1 <- ggplot(data2, aes(x = data2[[i]])) +
            geom_histogram(fill = "lightgreen") +
            xlab(x.axis.list[[i]])
        print(p1)
    })
}
```

In the past, I've been able to do something similar to this where I can just put `x.axis.list[[i]]` in my loop and change the symbols. However, I continue to get the term `expression` on the axis. So the symbol for Beta is correct as well as the subscript but the word "expression" remains. I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong, for a moment, I was able to produce a plot without "expression" but it has since stayed in the `ggplot`.

I want to be able to produce this plot, or one with the title on the y-axis without the word "expression".

My image currently looks [image: like this]. I'm not worried about this example data and the result of the plot, I'm wondering how to get rid of "expression" so only the math symbol shows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not exactly sure of what you want, can you write an x-axis label exactly as you want ?

Comment: I've added an updated example output. I don't understand why "expression" prints on the plot axis.

Comment: The problem seems to appear when I loop through the list of expressions. When I put a single expression in, I can get the output I am looking for, unfortunately, I want to update the axis for several plots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```r
for (i in seq_along(data2)) {
    df <- data2[i]
    names(df)[1] <- "x"
    myplots[[i]] <- local({
        p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x)) +
            geom_bar(fill = "lightgreen", stat = "count") +
            xlab(x.axis.list[[i]])
    })
}
```

And we can show all the plots together:

```r
library(patchwork)
(myplots[[1]] + myplots[[2]]) / (myplots[[3]] + myplots[[4]])
```

[image]

Note I created the expression list like this:

```r
x.axis.list <- lapply(1:4, function(i){
  parse(text = paste0("beta[paste(1, \",\", ", i, ")]"))
  })
```

Comment: How can I flip the numbers? so have `i` before the 1 in ```x.axis.list <- lapply(1:4, function(i){
  parse(text = paste0("beta[paste(1, \",\", ", i, ")]"))
  })```

Comment: @AW27 you can do `parse(text = paste0("beta[paste(", i, ", \",\", 1)]"))`