# Writing a fuction to Automate Repetitive Plotting in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hello I have a list (list1) that includes three dataframes. I would like to write a function to automate the task:

```
b<- ggplot(data = list1[[1]], mapping = aes(x = lag, y = acf)) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0)) +
  geom_segment(mapping = aes(xend = lag, yend = 0))
b
c<- ggplot(data = list1[[2]], mapping = aes(x = lag, y = acf)) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0)) +
  geom_segment(mapping = aes(xend = lag, yend = 0))
c
```

Any idea how to do that? I need to have the plots in order to use ggarrange later.

Comment: It might help to supply some example data and a mockup of how you would like to arrange the plots.

Comment: Consider using `lapply` to iterate over your data, as it is already a list.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/31993704/17144974

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Storing ggplot objects in a list from within loop in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31993704/storing-ggplot-objects-in-a-list-from-within-loop-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A great way to iterate over a list with a particular function would be to use `lapply()`.  Here is an example that should demonstrate the concept.

```
library(ggplot2)

# data frames put into a list
d1 <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10)
d2 <- data.frame(x=1:100, y=(1:100)^2)
d3 <- data.frame(x=1:200, y=log(1:200))

mylist <- list(d1, d2, d3)

# the custom function to be used for plotting
plot_function <- function(dat) {
  ggplot(dat, aes(x,y)) +
    geom_line(color="gray") + geom_point() +
    theme_bw()
}

myPlots <- lapply(mylist, plot_function)
```

This will store each plot as an element in a list of plots, `myPlots`.  You can address each plot individually via `myPlots[[1]]`, `myPlots[[2]]`, and `myPlots[[3]]`.

OP wanted to use this in `ggarrange` later, so it's sufficient to stop here, although it might be useful to know you can further use `lapply` along the index of a list.  This is useful for things like saving plots in a list, as you can see from the example below.

```
lapply(seq_along(myPlots),
  function(i) {
    ggsave(filename=paste0("plot",i,".png"), device = "png", plot = myPlots[[i]], width=6, height=3.5)
  }
)
```

This saves the plots as the following images.

[image]
[image]
[image]