# Avoid lazyness in ggplot aes(color=variable)

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, scope

In a for-loop I continue to add geom_... to a plot. I'd like each geom-object to have a separate color and a corresponding entry in the legend.

```
library(ggplot2)

means <- 1:5
sds <- 1:5

plt <- ggplot() + xlim(c(-10, 30))

for(i in 1:5) {
  plt <- plt + geom_function(fun = dnorm, 
                             args=c(mean=means[i], sd=sds[i]),
                             aes(color=paste(i)))
}

plt
```

However, I only get one color-group, corresponding to the final value of I.
How can I force ggplot to bind the value of `aes(color)` at the time I assign the variable?

Comment: Avoid the loop. Make your data tidy by pivoting longer. Or use a function from the `xapply` family.

Comment: You’ll need to use a local scope and copy the variable; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/31994539/1968

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `!!` in front of `paste(i)`

```r
means <- 1:5
sds <- 1:5

plt <- ggplot() + xlim(c(-10, 30))

for(i in 1:5) {
  plt <- plt + geom_function(fun = dnorm, args=c(mean=means[i], sd=sds[i]),
                             aes(color = !!paste(i)))
}
plt
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Or use `local()` to create a new scope:

```r
library(ggplot2)
means <- 1:5
sds <- 1:5

plt <- ggplot() + xlim(c(-10, 30))

for(i in 1:5) {
  plt <- local({
    i <- i
    plt <- plt + geom_function(fun = dnorm, 
                                    args=c(mean=means[i], sd=sds[i]),
                                    aes(color=paste(i)))
  })
}

plt
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>