# ggplot2 overwrites plots when saving in a list

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've a code to plot some data from a dataframe.
When I run the code without the loop it works, but when I do it using the code and then do `plots[[1]]` `plots[[2]]` all plots are the same but the labs are different.

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks

```
#-- Plots
plots <- list()
combinations <- combn(dim(ssgsea.diff)[2],2)

for (i in 1:dim(combinations)[2]){

  fit <- lm(ssgsea.diff[,combinations[1,i]] ~ ssgsea.diff[,combinations[2,i]], 
            data = ssgsea.diff)

  plot1 <- ggplot(ssgsea.diff) + 
    aes(ssgsea.diff[,combinations[1,i]], ssgsea.diff[,combinations[2,i]]) + 
    geom_point()

  plot1 <- plot1 + 
    labs(x = names(ssgsea.diff)[combinations[1,i]], 
         y = names(ssgsea.diff)[combinations[2,i]]) + 
    geom_smooth(method="lm", col = "red") + 
    labs(title = paste("Adj R2 = ", signif(summary(fit)$adj.r.squared, 5), 
                       " Slope =",signif(fit$coef[[2]], 5), 
                       " Pval =",signif(summary(fit)$coef[2,4], 5)))

  plots[[i]] <- plot1
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the dataset used here in `dput()` form? Alternatively make this problem reproducible using one of the common datasets from `datasets` package.

Comment: I cannot provide the dataset. But basically, there is something in the code, that all the plots saved in the list `plots` look like the last plot created. This happens even when the code works of out of the loop.

Answer (score 4):

Since no data is provided, I'll attempt to demonstrate with a common dataset from R:

```
data(airquality)
ssgsea.diff <- as.data.frame(airquality)

plots <- list()
combinations <- combn(dim(ssgsea.diff)[2],2)
```

**Reproduce** the problem using the original code. There are 15 plots after the for loop's completion, & indeed they all share the same graph with different labels:

```
for (i in 1:dim(combinations)[2]){

  fit <- lm(ssgsea.diff[,combinations[1,i]] ~ ssgsea.diff[,combinations[2,i]], 
            data = ssgsea.diff)

  plot1 <- ggplot(ssgsea.diff) + 
    aes(ssgsea.diff[,combinations[1,i]], ssgsea.diff[,combinations[2,i]]) + 
    geom_point()

  plot1 <- plot1 + 
    labs(x = names(ssgsea.diff)[combinations[1,i]], 
         y = names(ssgsea.diff)[combinations[2,i]]) + 
    geom_smooth(method="lm", col = "red") + 
    labs(title = paste("Adj R2 = ", signif(summary(fit)$adj.r.squared, 5), 
                       " Slope =",signif(fit$coef[[2]], 5), 
                       " Pval =",signif(summary(fit)$coef[2,4], 5)))

  plots[[i]] <- plot1
}
```

**Solution** below will result in 15 different plots stored in the list (I also defined the column indices first, to make the code more readable):

```
for (i in 1:dim(combinations)[2]){

  # define column indices & column names first
  C1 <- combinations[1, i]; C1.name <- names(ssgsea.diff)[C1]
  C2 <- combinations[2, i]; C2.name <- names(ssgsea.diff)[C2]

  fit <- lm(ssgsea.diff[, C1] ~ ssgsea.diff[, C2]) # no need to specify data here

  plot1 <- ggplot(ssgsea.diff) + 
    aes_string(C1.name, C2.name) + geom_point()

  plot1 <- plot1 + 
    labs(x = C1.name, y = C2.name) + 
    geom_smooth(method="lm", col = "red") + 
    labs(title = paste("Adj R2 = ", signif(summary(fit)$adj.r.squared, 5), 
                       " Slope =", signif(fit$coef[[2]], 5), 
                       " Pval =", signif(summary(fit)$coef[2, 4], 5)))

  plots[[i]] <- plot1
}

rm(C1, C2, C1.name, C2.name, fit, plot1, i)
```

**Explanation**: Due to the way you specified the aesthetic mapping for ggplot, all the plot objects were evaluated at the end of the loop with the current (i.e. last) value of `i`. A safer method would be to take advantage of the `data` argument in ggplot, which stores the data frame in the ggplot object itself as a *copy* rather than a *reference*. When `i` changes through each loop, the data copy in the ggplot object does not change. Answers in these two posts discuss this further: [Storing ggplot objects in a list from within loop in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31993704/storing-ggplot-objects-in-a-list-from-within-loop-in-r) & [Storing plot objects in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820590/storing-plot-objects-in-a-list).

Comment: Same problem can arise when getting variable - e.g., aes(get(variable)) - can be remedied by using aes_string

Comment: great explanation thank you! This really bugged me for quite some time :)