# rePost: Generating names iteratively in R for storing plots (2009)

Tags: r, object, loops, plot

A previous post provided a solution to iteratively store plots in R: see [... iteratively in R...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816480/generating-names-iteratively-in-r-for-storing-plots?tab=oldest#tab-top) .  I had a similar problem and after reading and implementing the solutions provided by the post I am still unable to solve my problem.

The previous post provided the following code:

> # Create a list to hold the plot objects.
>
> `pltList <- list()`
>
> `for( i in 2:15 ){`
>
> # Get data, perform analysis, ect.
>
> # Create plot name.
>     `pltName <- paste( 'a', i, sep = '' )`
>
> # Store a plot in the list using the
>   name as an index.
>    `pltList[[ pltName ]] <- plot()`
>
> }

The following is my code implementation:

```
a <- list.files("F:.../4hrs", pattern='.csv')
pltList <- list()
i=1

for (x in a) {
    myfiles <- read.csv(a, header=TRUE, as.is=TRUE, nrows=2500)

    h <- hist(data, plot=F)
    # perform analysis, ect.

    pltName <- paste('a', formatC(i, width=2, flag='0'), sep='')
    pltList[[ pltName ]] <- plot(h)
    i <- i+1

  }
```

`pltName` does produce a list of names but `pltList` is of length zero.

I am not sure why `pltList` is not being assigned the plots.
What I eventually want to do is create a `pltList` with multiple plots contained therein.  Then plot those plots in `par(mfrow=c(2,1))` style and export as a .pdf.

I should mention that the above works for

```
pltList[[ pltName ]] <- xyplot(h)
```

but then I am unable to plot multiple plots in the style of `par(mfrow=c(2,1))`.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: This strategy will only work for lattice and ggplot2 plots because base R plots usually don't return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original question you referenced and my answer to it, `plot()` was used as an abstract placeholder for a plotting function that returned an object and not a literal call to the R function `plot`. Most functions that return graphics objects are based on the 'grid' package such as `xyplot` from the lattice package or `qplot` from ggplot2.

Sorry for the confusion, I should have made this point clear in my answer, but I did not as the asker of the question was already aware of it.

Base graphics functions such as `hist` and `plot` render directly to output and do not return any objects that can be used to recreate the plot at a later time which is why you are ending up with a list of length zero.

In order to use this approach you will have to trade usage of the `hist` function for something that returns an object.  Using ggplot2, you could do something like the following in your loop:

```
# Don't call your data variable 'data' or ggplot will confuse it with the
# `data` function and suffer an error.
h <- qplot(x = plot_data)

pltName <- paste('a', formatC(i, width=2, flag='0'), sep='')
pltList[[ pltName ]] <- h
```

I have edited my answer to the previous question to make it clear that the use of `plot()` in my example is not an actual call to the R function of the same name.

Comment: Thanks Sharpie... this really helped in clarifying my 'object-less' assignment.  I am using `xyplot()` with the lattice package.  `pltList[[ pltName ]] <- xyplot()`

Answer (score 0):

Your code uses files I don't have so I can't replicate it, I am also not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish, but I do see some problems in the code that might help fix it:

```
a <- list.files("F:.../4hrs", pattern='.csv')
```

I am not fammiliar with `list.files`, Is this correctly assigning `a`? `.csv` seems an odd pattern.

```
pltList <- list()
i=1

for (x in a) {


 myfiles <- read.csv(a, header=TRUE, as.is=TRUE, nrows=2500)
```

Here I think `a` is a vector containing the filenanes right? You are looping `x` for every value of `a`, however I don't see `x` return anywhere in the code. Also you are reading a vector of filenames here. Shouldnt this be `read.csv(x,...`, or better yet, loop `for (i in 1:length(a))` and index `a[i]`.

```
    h <- hist(data, plot=F)
```

I don't see the object `data` anywhere. Is `h` correctly assigned?

```
# perform analysis, ect.

    pltName <- paste('a', formatC(i, width=2, flag='0'), sep='')
    pltList[[ pltName ]] <- plot(h)
    i <- i+1
  }
```

What I like to do is simply run such a loop by hand, and see what is going on. I think there is a problem in the assigning of `myfiles` or `h`

Comment: `a<-list.files()` just provides the names of the files that I would like to read.  `myfiles <- read.csv(a, ...)` actually reads in the data.  As Sharpie mentioned above Base Graphics do not create an object so `h` is not correctly assigned.  Thanks for you suggestion!