# Storing plot objects in R

Tags: r, object, plot

Two methods of storing plot objects in list or a name string are mentioned on this page [Generating names iteratively in R for storing plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816480/generating-names-iteratively-in-r-for-storing-plots) . But both do not seem to work on my system.

```
> plist = list()
> plist[[1]] = plot(1:30)
> 
> plist
list()
> 
> plist[[1]]
Error in plist[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Second method:

```
> assign('pp', plot(1:25))
> 
> pp
NULL
```

I am using:

```
> R.version
               _                           
platform       i486-pc-linux-gnu           
arch           i486                        
os             linux-gnu                   
system         i486, linux-gnu             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          2.0                         
year           2015                        
month          04                          
day            16                          
svn rev        68180                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
nickname       Full of Ingredients
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: The base graphics plotting functions (ie `plot()`) do not return objects. That would only work for lattice (eg `xyplot()`) or ggplot objects (er `qplot()`). The accepted answer to that question is misleading.

Answer (score 3):

Use `recordPlot` and `replayPlot`:

```
plot(BOD)
plt <- recordPlot()
plot(0)
replayPlot(plt)
```